# uDig window to change between historical dates?

Tags: postgresql, query, eclipse, query-layer, udig

I'm new to uDig, but I'm experienced Java developer. I have points with temperature measurements that change overtime in SQL database. I would like to give user ability to change between historical data.

Is there window in uDig which allows this? 
If not: Can you point me where to start to write a plugin allowing this?

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago we added time browsing support to the map viewport in order to be able to view netcdfs along a timeline (see https://code.google.com/p/jgrass/wiki/SummerOfCode2009 ).

So if I got your problem right, I think you should be able to use directly the map window and pilot time through the navigation view.

What will be necessary for you to do, is an implementation of your datasource as a uDig catalog service, in order to be able to support time browsing.

You might want to ask in the uDig mailinglist for implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help but the description of the problem is not enough to give an exact advise.

But if you have a data in Postgresql in some table and they are points with a location (there is a geometry column) and also there is an attribute with a timestamp (or something like this).. Import PostGIS service to catalog, add the underlying table with points as a layer to the map, check projections, etc (basic stuff), then in properties dialog of the layer there is "Query" page where an advanced user may specify a query using basic SQL-like operands and sentences as "TIMESTAMP_FIELD BETWEEN 'some date' AND 'some date' " .. Something like this, again.

In the end it's just a Filter object being set to Layer object that causes loading the data and rendering it on the map accordingly given filtering criteria.

If you need custom UI, configure development environment with UDIG SDK and implement some custom UI view or dialog where users may manage filtering criteria that becomes a Filter object being passed to Layer and...   see above:)

Answer (score 0):

Quick google search : http://goo.gl/ZO0JSH

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend posting your question on uDig dev list over at LocationTech. I know the core developers would be interested in this. [uDig dev mailing list](https://www.locationtech.org/mailman/listinfo/udig-dev)

Comment: why did your edit remove the vote i received?

Comment: Not sure if you've checked mailing list above. Jody Garnett posted the following there yesterday --- Andrea did a time control view for jgrass that may work. Time should be part of the viewport just like any other bounding box, CRS or elevation setting used to explore a data set.

What is missing is a way to mark an attribute as being a time stamp for filtering.

Short term fix is to use ECQL filter on the layer.